# How to assign an SKPhysicsBody around a sprite node so its wraps around the objects frame perfectly

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I'm trying to make a physics body that outlines the sprite node, example: instead of using SKPhysicsBody(circleOfSize...) and just getting the circle shape or using SKPhysicsBody(RectangleOfSize...) but i thought there was an "AlphaMask" or something like that that would allow, say if my sprite node was the shape of a cup or a "V" shape that would allow objects into the open top and get caught inside the "V"? thanks in advance :)

[image] [image]

so the first picture is what i keep getting when i try the rectangle one and the second picture is the type i need!

Comment: Create a physics body from a texture. Or create it from a path. (check docs to find out which initializers SKPhysicsBody has).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using a PNG image (or any image type that supports clear pixels), you can just create a `physicsBody` from a texture:

```
let sprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Spaceship")
sprite.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: sprite.texture!, size: sprite.texture!.size())
```

This creates a `physicsBody` based on the clear and coloured pixels of the texture to do its best at matching the shape.

Be warned that using this isn't always 100% accurate and may cause issues if used with highly complex textures (lag, memory issues, etc...)

As per Apples Docs:

> When choosing a shape for your physics 
>    body, do not be overly precise.
>    More complex shapes require more work to be properly simulated.
>
> [SKPhysicsBody Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/reference/spritekit/skphysicsbody)

Comment: yup i defenitly forgot too add that its an SKSpritenode image named:"" thanks worked!

Answer (score 3):

I think the best solution could be to build a path and after to make:

```
SKPhysicsBody.init(edgeLoopFrom: path!)
```

This is the official source documentation:

```
/**
     Creates an edge loop from a path. A loop is automatically created by joining the last point to the first. The path must have no self intersection. Edges have no volume and are intended to be used to create static environments. Edges can collide with body's of volume, but not with each other.
     @param path the path to use
     */
    public /*not inherited*/ init(edgeLoopFrom path: CGPath)
```

With this solution you will able to define precisely your shape following `CGPath`  construction (the 'V' shape).